# creating and pushing files in a structured github repository

Tags: git, github, terminal, repository, git-push

How can I create a sub-folder (with files) using terminal in a github project, knowing that I'll work on those files and push them to the sub-folder of that specific project/directory?

For example:

```
myproject
    |_work00 (to push changes in this folder)  
    |_work01
    |_work02
```

Any idea by any chance?!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First, if you have only one GitHub repository, you can simply add files in your subfolders, and push from anywhere within `myproject`: said files will appear on the remote GitHub "`myproject`" repository.

But, second, if you want one GitHub repository per `workxx` folder, you can create them on GitHub, and then, in the myproject repository, [add them as submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

```
cd /path/to/myproject
git submodule add https://github.com/<me>/work00
```

You can then work in those submodule, add, commit and push from each one.

But you will also have to add, commit and push from `myproject`, in order to register those submodules new state.